# Como agrego fotos en los controladores de Asp.Net MVC EF code First

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

he creado un controlador en el que quiero guardar fotos de pérfil. Y luego poder consultar esa imagen........

---

El modelo que he creado es el siguiente:

```
 public class Cliente
    {
        [Key]
        public string Codigo { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(200)]
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public byte[] Foto { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public bool  Estado { get; set; }
    }
```

Y eso me creo una vista como la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero como verán no me creo ningun control donde la persona pueda subir la foto. Mi pregunta es como puedo modificar el código para que me agregue un botón o lo que sea donde la person agregue una foto y esta se guarde en la base de datos SQL Server.

Adjunto el código de la vista :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el código de el controlador:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código de la vista......................

```
@model WebApplication24.Models.Cliente

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Cliente</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Codigo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Codigo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Codigo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nombre, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nombre, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nombre, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Foto, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Foto, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Foto, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Estado, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Estado)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Estado, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}

Código del controlador .............................

 // POST: Clientes/Create
        // Para protegerse de ataques de publicación excesiva, habilite las propiedades específicas a las que desea enlazarse. Para obtener 
        // más información vea https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "Codigo,Nombre,Foto,Estado")] Cliente cliente)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Cliente.Add(cliente);
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(cliente);
        }
```

Comment: Por favor, por el código de la Vista y el Controlador en texto, no en imágenes.

Comment: @RafaelAcosta listo

Answer (score 1):

Para subir imágenes (o cualquier otro archivo) al servidor, necesitas hacerlo a través de un control `<input type="file" />` en tu Vista.

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Foto, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="file" id="foto" name="foto" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

A nivel de Controlador, deberás recibir este archivo a través de una instancia de la clase **`HttpPostedFileBase`** en la Acción correspondiente:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> SubirArchivo(HttpPostedFileBase foto) { ... }
```

En tu caso, deberás adaptar tu Acción `Create()` para que reciba tu Modelo de datos `Cliente` y además el archivo (foto). Sería algo así:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(Cliente cliente, HttpPostedFileBase foto)
```

Como entenderás, son muchas las modificaciones en tu código las que habría que hacer, como para exponerlas aquí. Pero te dejo el enlace de un artículo en español, donde podrás ver paso a paso como subir tus fotos al servidor en una aplicación ASP.NET MVC:

[Cómo subir archivos al servidor en una aplicación ASP.NET MVC](http://www.rafaelacosta.net/Blog/2018/7/30/c%C3%B3mo-subir-archivos-al-servidor-en-una-aplicaci%C3%B3n-aspnet-mvc)